# Proving an AC current with peak amplitude of 311V is equivalent to a DC current of 220V

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage

If one starts with an alternating current in the form of a sin wave with a peak amplitude of 311V and then goes through the usual RMS procedure of integrating $sin^2$ from 0 to 2$\pi$ then the result is that $$311V DC = \frac{311}{\sqrt{2}} = 220V AC$$

But instead of squaring the sin at the start if I just get twice the integral of sinx from 0 to $\pi$ , I end up with 
not: $$311\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 220$$
but: $$311\frac{2}{\pi} = 198$$

It seems that the true area of a sin curve from 0 to $2\pi$ with a peak amp of 311 should be 198 x 2$\pi$ , not 220 x 2$\pi$.

I'm confused as to why we use the RMS method here.

Comment: So, the root of your confusion is what RMS is meant to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to start out by defining how a AC and DC voltage can be "equivalent".  An AC and DC voltage are considered equal if they cause the same heating in a simple resistive load.

Given a resistive load, we can calculate P = IV and I = V/R, so P = V²/R.  So the power dissipated in the load is proportional to the voltage squared.

So to get the DC equivalent of an AC signal, average the squares of the instantaneous voltages over one cycle, then square-root to get back to units of Volts (rather than Volts-squared).  In other words, take the RMS of the voltage.